# Ruby: How to 'next' an external loop?

Tags: ruby, iteration

```
file.each_line do |line|
  #skip the first one/not a user
  3.times { next } if first == 1
  first = 2
end
```

How can I get the 'next' to well, "next" the iteration of the each_line, instead of the 3.times iteration? Also, how can I write this to look better (ie: first == 1 looks bad)

Comment: Can you please describe what you are attempting to achieve, rather than how you are trying to achieve it?  There's probably a fairly simple way to do it.

Comment: Oh sure, I am just trying to skip the first 3 lines in a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `drop` method to, er, drop first couple of elements:

```
File.open('bar').each_line.drop(3).each do |line|
  puts line
end
```

Comment: Yes, this works in 1.8.7.  Nicer than my answer: It says what it means.

Comment: For MRI < 1.8.7, just require 'backports'.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop can set a flag variable (say, `break_out = true`) before it `break`s and you can check that variable as soon as you come out of the inner loop.  If you detect the flag is set, break out of the outer loop.

More likely, there is a better way of structuring your code to do what you want.  Are you simply wanting to skip the first three lines?  If so, try something like:

```
line_count = 0
file.each_line do |line|
  #skip the first one/not a user
  line_count += 1
  next if (line_count <= 3 && first == 1)
  first = 2
end
```

Comment: Yeah that is one way. I wonder if there is a more well, i don't know... poetic way to write it

Comment: I suppose there's always `file = IO.readlines("filename")[3..-1]` (if all you want to do is ignore the first three lines and read in the rest)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to add another if statement in there

```
file.each_line do |line|
  #skip the first one/not a user
  3.times { next } if first == 1
  break if something
  first = 2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file isn't too large, you can do

```
file.read.split("\n")[3..-1].each do |line_you_want|
  puts line_you_want
end
```